# How do I stop my array of objects from being overwritten?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Ok, so this is a part of my main method:

```
    public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
   //Variables to place data attributes of object in
    String teacherName;
    int teacherId;
    double basicSalary;
    double extraPaymentRate;
    int numOfCourses=100;
    Course []coursesTaught=new Course[numOfCourses];
    String courseName;
    int courseId;
    int y;
    System.out.println("Please enter number of teachers:");
    y=scan.nextInt();
    Teacher []teacherArray=new Teacher[y];
    for(int i=0;i<y;i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter teacher’s name, id, basic salary, and extra payment rate: ");
        teacherName=scan.next();
        teacherId=scan.nextInt();
        basicSalary=scan.nextDouble();
        extraPaymentRate=scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter number of courses taught: ");
        numOfCourses=scan.nextInt();
        for(int j=0;j<numOfCourses;j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter course names and IDs:");
            courseName=scan.next();
            courseId=scan.nextInt();
            coursesTaught[j]=new Course(courseName,courseId);
        }
        teacherArray[i]=new Teacher(teacherName,teacherId,basicSalary,extraPaymentRate,numOfCourses,coursesTaught);
    }
```

now my problem is that every time i add a new teacher object, the new courses i add to that teacher object override the last one. **so all the teacher have the same courses**

here's the teacher class

```
public class Teacher {
       private String name;
       private int id;
       private double basicSalary;
       private double extraPaymentRate;
       public static int numOfCourses;
       public Course []coursesTaught= new Course[numOfCourses];
public Teacher() {

}
public Teacher(String name,int id,double basicSalary,double 
    extraPaymentRate,int numOfCourses,Course []coursesTaught) {
    this.name=name;
    this.id=id;
    this.basicSalary=basicSalary;
    this.extraPaymentRate=extraPaymentRate;
    Teacher.numOfCourses=numOfCourses;
    this.coursesTaught=coursesTaught;
}
//setter and getter methods here
```

and here's the course class

```
public class Course {
public String name;
public int id;
public Course() {

}
public Course(String name,int id) {
    this.name=name;
    this.id=id;
}
```

I'm still grasping the objects concept. Any help?

Comment: You have a single `coursesTaught` array. You need one for each teacher.

Answer (score 4):

```
Course []coursesTaught=new Course[numOfCourses];
```

is declared before the loop.
So you instantiate this once and all created `Teacher` instances use the same in the loop :

```
Course []coursesTaught = new Course[numOfCourses];
...
Teacher []teacherArray = new Teacher[y];
for(int i=0;i<y;i++) {
   teacherArray[i] = new Teacher(teacherName,teacherId,basicSalary,extraPaymentRate,numOfCourses,coursesTaught);
   ...
}
```

Declare `coursesTaught`  in the loop that creates and populates each `Teacher` instance in order to instantiate `coursesTaught` at each iteration and consequently to attach it to the current  created `Teacher` instance :

```
...
Teacher []teacherArray=new Teacher[y];
for(int i=0;i<y;i++) {
    Course []coursesTaught = new Course[numOfCourses];
    teacherArray[i] = new Teacher(teacherName,teacherId,basicSalary,extraPaymentRate,numOfCourses,coursesTaught);
    ...
}
```